# TextBox outline being overlayed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

So I have a little problem and I don't understand why it is doing it. I have a textbox, which uses JavaScript for client side validation and also C# for server side validation, so as you can see from the screen shot below, I have done some server side validation so when the user clicks to register without having more than 6 characters entered in the textbox, the textbox would then have a red outline:

[image: When the user hasn't entered anything]
However because I also have JavaScript for client side validation, when a user types in more than 6 characters the textbox should have a green outline, which the screenshot below demonstrates it does, but the server side validation textbox outline still remains underneath so you can still see the red outline under the green:

[image: Client side validation]

I just don't understand why this is happening as of from my knowledge the outline property is the same for each textbox so why is creating new outlines?

This is my code for client side validation (JavaScipt):

```
function checkPassword(password)
{
    password_txt = document.getElementById('<%= password_txt.ClientID %>');
    if (password == '')
    {
        password_lbl.innerHTML = 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
        password_lbl.style.color = "red";
        password_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"
        //register_btn.disabled = true;
        passwordCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        password_lbl.innerHTML = 'Perfect!';
        password_lbl.style.color = "green";
        password_txt.style.outline = "1px solid green"
        //register_btn.disabled = true;
    }
```

The checkPassword is called using a keyup event on the textbox. Now this is the server side validation:

```
if (password_txt.Text == "")
{
    password_lbl.Text = "Password must be at least 6 characters";
    password_lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    password_txt.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    password_txt.BorderWidth = 1;
    password_txt.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
    register_btn.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    password_lbl.Text = "Perfect!";
    password_lbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    password_txt.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    password_txt.BorderWidth = 1;
    password_txt.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
    register_btn.Enabled = false;
    passwordCheck = true;
}
```

Which is called using an OnClick.

Does anyone understand why it is acting is such a way?

Comment: You might also try clearing the `.outline` property before setting it to green `.outline = "0px"` before `.outline = "1px solid green`

Comment: @musefan Perfect that worked! I still don't understand why it was different with outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the "border" from server code, but setting "outline" using JS. These are not the same thing so it is not overwriting the style.

In your javascript, change this:

```
password_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"
```

to this:

```
password_txt.style.border = "1px solid red";
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/qoe25y4f/) that shows how they differ

Comment: So basically from your example, the outline is what surrounds the border and not the textbox itself?

Comment: [From here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp): An outline is a line that is drawn around elements (**outside the borders**) to make the element "stand out".